# Is the degree of a field extension inferiorly bounded by the degree of irreducible polynomials?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $\overline K$ be the algebraic closure of a field $K$.
Let us suppose that there exists a polynomial $P\in K[X]$ that is irreducible over $K$.

Do we have $\deg P\leq[\overline K:K]$?

If so, is there a more general result where we would replace $\overline K$ with an arbitrary extension?

Comment: Sorry about that. I posted on wrong question.

Comment: @Wolgwang Oh okay, no problem

Comment: With $a\in \overline{K}$ a root of $P$  then $K(\alpha)$ is a $\deg P$ dimensional $K$-vector space. Whence $\overline{K}$ is at least a $\deg P$ dimensional $K$-vector space.